# Removing a file after sql execution in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to read multiple .sql files and then execute them into the database. This works, although now I am in need of deleting the file after its been successfully been imported to the database.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

```
<?php 
function scan_for_sql_files($path){
    $itdir = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);
    $files = array();
    foreach ($itdir as $path=>$dir){
        if ($dir->isFile()){
            $ext = substr(strtolower($path), -3);
            if($ext == 'sql'){
                $files[] = array('path' => $path);
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}

//get files
$files = scan_for_sql_files('mysqls');
//Do sql
foreach($files as $file){
    $sql = file_get_contents($file['path']);
    $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps simply using [unlink()](http://www.php.net/unlink)

Comment: Maybe I miss a point, but you don't know how to `unlink` the file?

Comment: have you tried to add this code 
`if($qr = $dbh->exec($sql))
unlink($file['path']);`

Comment: Note that StackOverflow likes you to reward answers to your questions when they have been helpful by `accepting` them.... you seem not to like accepting answers, though you're certainly using code from those answers

Comment: You have to check if an error occurred during exec; `if ($qr) { unlink($file['path']); } else { echo "problem with {$file['path']}"; }`

Comment: @MarkBaker you are right, but the question is too easy compared with the existing code,  i was thinking that i have not understand the requirement :D

Comment: What type of object is `$dbh` and what does it return on success/failure of `$dbh->exec()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unlink()` function to delete the file.

`unlink('test.html');`

```
foreach($files as $file){
  $sql = file_get_contents($file['path']);
  $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
   if(is_file($file['path'])){
     unlink($file['path']);
   }
}
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/unlink

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "unlink" function to get rid of the file

Simple modification :

```
foreach($files as $file){
   $sql = file_get_contents($file['path']);
   $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
   unlink($file['path']);
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp

["Unlink" reference](https://www.php.net/unlink)

Comment: This answer is dangerous. You don't check for errors of 'exec' function. You may very well lose some data due to an error in an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete your sql file by this

unlink('database.sql');

or

you can delete sql file content by this

file_put_contents("database.sql", "");

if you are working on window os don't worry but if you are working in linux you have to set permission of all sql file  other wise your file will not access by your php script